# Unable to download TeamCity windows tray notifier when TeamCity running over HTTPS with IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, teamcity, teamcity-7.0, teamcity-7.1

My TeamCity Server uses SSL (the address is https://server.sufix). When trying to download the TeamCity windows tray notifier using IE8, I receive an error:

> Unable to download TrayNotifierInstaller.msi from... Unable to open this Internet site. The request site is either unavailable or cannot be found. Please try again later

This is a known limitation of IE8 that prevents downloads over https in [some cases](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/03/internet-explorer-cannot-download-over-https-when-no-cache.aspx).

Is there a way to bypass this with TeamCity?

Comment: I'm confused. Your title states that downloading "works with https" whereas the question implies that it doesn't. If you're saying that it doesn't work over https, have you got any evidence that https is the issue?

Comment: When team city was not using SSL I could download the tray. After I upgraded it to work with SSL I couldn't download it any more. Now I'm trying to make the download possible again using SSL

Answer (score 0):

This is a minor problem I've run into when trying to download via the link in the tray notifier.

You can log in to TeamCity, go to "My Settings and Tools", and the download link is on the right side.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [Windows Tray Notifier](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/windows-tray-notifier.html) has been deprecated and the install link (in TeamCity Tools) has been removed:
[image]

TeamCity recommends using the [Browser Notifier](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/browser-notifier.html#Working+with+Browser+Notifier) instead, which can be downloaded from the same place (TeamCity Tools). Current supported browsers are Chrome, Edge, Firefox, and Opera.